# i can't open .onion sites on tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, darknet

Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site.

We can’t connect to the server at ecleg2gwe2edwiuf.onion.
If that address is correct, here are three other things you can try:

```
Try again later.
Check your network connection.
If you are connected but behind a firewall, check that Tor Browser has permission to access the Web.
```

I am getting this error but i can open other sites like duckduckgo but i cant open .onion sites 
plz help me...

Comment: Why do you think that address works? It looks like it’s down temporarily or permanently.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked the entered Onion both in TOR browser and Tor2Web service. Non of them, could load the address. Maybe the link is down which is normal in TOR network.

[image]

Suggesting check in other time or contact the owner if you have access.